# Play store console detects android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE requirement for a Vanilla React Native app

Tags: react-native

1. I created a react native app using react-native init. Did not change a single line of code. (Note: react-native version is 0.55.4)
2. I generated a singed release APK by following steps given in [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html).
3. I tried to upload this APK to Google Play console.

I got the following error:

**Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)**

This is an unexpected behaviour right? Why will a vanilla app require this permission? How can I solve this issue?

**Edit 1**

My Android manifest is the default one created by react-native init.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.praveenavtestproject">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

**Edit 2**

My app doesn't need any permission to work. It just displays 3 lines of text from a historical literature. It is just for information purpose. In Play Store Console, under Store listing tab, at the bottom, there is a Privacy Policy section. *It says If you wish to provide a privacy policy URL for this application, please enter it below. Also, please check out our User Data policy to avoid common violations.*

I am not providing a privacy policy URL. My app is not supposed to be accessing any user data or phone state. Does React Native access it by default? Can that be the reason for this issue?

**Edit 3** 
Looks like this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12965) is already being looked at by React Native team.

Comment: What does your AndroidManifest.xml look like?

Comment: @Kai I have updated the question with AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I am getting the same crap. Playstore says I require this permission but nowhere in my app do I use it or request it.